# Edit Components of a Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, storyboard

I have dragged a navigation bar to the top of my UITableViewController in the storyboard. In `viewDidLoad` I want to update the title in the navigation controller but `[self setTitle=@"New Title"];` is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
IBOutlet UINavigationItem* barItem = /*(the bar your want to change in storyboard)*/;
barItem.title = @"new title";
```

If you want to change it, use `barItem.title = ...` or `self.navigationItem.title = ...`
You must ensure that the view controller (`self`) inherits from `UINavigationController`.

Comment: I linked the UINavigationbar to my header file with `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationItem *bar;`. However in the implementation file for `[_bar.title = @"newTitle"];` xcode is saying that it is missing an identifier.